# How do I determine if a port is in use, e.g. via netstat?

Tags: shell, unix, port, netstat

I am trying to check port availability and get a return value using shell script. Example: if port 8080 is free then return true, else return false. Can anyone help? I tried with `netstat`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you are using netstat from net-tools, this is a working example:

```
function is_port_free { 

    netstat -ntpl | grep [0-9]:${1:-8080} -q ; 

    if [ $? -eq 1 ]
    then 
        echo yes 
    else 
        echo no
    fi
}
```

- ${1:-8080} means use first argument as port and 8080 if no first argument
- grep -q [0-9]:port means match a number followed by a colon followed by port
- $? is the exit value of the previous command. Zero means all went well. Exit values above 0 indicate an error condition. In the context of grep, exit code 1 means no match. The -q means don't do anything but return the exit value.
- netstat -ltnp means list **n**umeric ports and IPs for all **p**rograms that are **l**istening on a **t**cp port.
- a | b means process standard output of a with b

eg.

```
$ is_port_free 8080
yes

$ is_port_free 22
no
```

Answer (score 18):

`lsof` is your friend:

```
# lsof -i:8080      # free on my machine
# echo $?
1
# lsof -i:5353      # occupied
COMMAND   PID           USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mDNSRespo  64 _mdnsresponder    8u  IPv4 0x9853f646e2fecbb7      0t0  UDP *:mdns
mDNSRespo  64 _mdnsresponder    9u  IPv6 0x9853f646e2fec9cf      0t0  UDP *:mdns
# echo $?
0
```

So in a script, you could use `!` to negate the value to test for availability:

```
if ! lsof -i:8080
then
    echo 8080 is free
else
    echo 8080 is occupied
fi
```

Comment: And one can also redirect the output of `lsof` to `/dev/null` to make it more "scripty".

Comment: It may also be useful to `grep` for `LISTEN`. Something like `if ! lsof -i:8080 | grep LISTEN > /dev/null`. This may be useful if you have a server running locally as well as an outgoing connection. For example, you're connected to a remote MySQL server while you also have a local MySQL server running. The outgoing connection would be listed with `ESTABLISHED`. These would need to be filtered out if you only want to know if there's a local port being used.

Comment: Instead of filtering with `grep`, one could use `lsof -i:8080 -sTCP:LISTEN > /dev/null`.

Answer (score 1):

How about something simple:

```
netstat -an|egrep '[0-9]:8080 .+LISTENING'
```